# SqlDatasource connect to SQL Server 2008 in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to use the SqlDatasource to connect a SQL Server 2008, but it says it only support the sql server 2005. Is there any method to solve it? I use the Visual Studio 2008.

Best Regards,

Comment: show us your connection string!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlDatasource` will connect to SQL Server 2008

Comment: What do you mean "will"? You mean it can not for mow?

Comment: Have you _tried_ it?  SqlDatasource works just fine with sql server 2008 right now, and it only takes a moment to test this and see for yourself.

Comment: Then you configured something wrong.  It _does_ work for sql server 2008.

Comment: Ok, I will try to install the VS 2008 SP1 first to see what would be like after installation.

Answer (score 1):

For design time connectivity (ie. Server Explorer) from Visual Studio 2005 you need to install this patch: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Support](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e1109aef-1aa2-408d-aa0f-9df094f993bf&displaylang=en).

For design time connectivity from Visual Studio 2008 you need to install VS 2008 SP1, if I remember correctly.